# google sheets & custom function to compare strings

Tags: google-apps-script

Basic Idea:
I have a string in cell D2 on the first sheet.
I want to put a custom function in cell G2 that compares the D2
 string with some text, and if it matches, output the value of F2
to H2, ( where it will be updated on sheet2 with =Sheet1!H2 in a cell on sheet2.

a little convoluted, but i have little scripting knowledge, 
and don't know the syntax well enuff to figure all this out.

here is what i'm trying , ( not working) in cell G2.

```
function compareString() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var name_Cell = sheet.getRange("D2");  // ('D2');
  var url_Cell = sheet.getRange("F2"); 
  if ( name_Cell == "Burning man-Limbo" )
  { 
   //var nextSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Limbo");
   //nextSheet.getRange(A2).setValues(url_Cell);
     var cell = sheet.getRange("H2"); 
     return cell.setValue(url_Cell);
  }
  else
  {  throw ("Danger Will Robinson: input bad : " + name_Cell);
     return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to App Engine, and it doesn't require an outside function.  Just put this in cell F2:

`=IF(D2="Burning man-Limbo", H2, "Danger Will Robinson: input bad : " + D2)`

Answer (score 1):

`sheet.getRange(...)` returns a `Range` object. You will have to use `getValue()` to retrieve the `string` value for that cell.

for example:

```
if (name_Cell.getValue() == "Burning man-Limbo")
{ 
 //var nextSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Limbo");
 //nextSheet.getRange(A2).setValues(url_Cell.getValue());
   var cell = sheet.getRange("H2"); 
   return cell.setValue(url_Cell.getValue());
}
```